# Increment GitVersion per build

Tags: azure-devops, semantic-versioning, gitversion

Talking about [`UseGitVersion@5` Azure DevOps task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gittools.usegitversion-test), which is a wrapper around the actual GitVersion tool. I looked at the various GitVersion configuration options, but I could not find anything that will increment per *build*. Not per commit, per build. I have a build counter value I can pass to GitVersion, if it would be willing to accept it somehow, but I don't see any argument or option to use it.

The only option I found so far is to override the `next-version` value in `GitVersion.yml`, but I would prefer to increment the PreReleaseTag rather than the semver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [include environment variables](https://gitversion.net/docs/configuration#assembly-file-versioning-format) in the various `*-format` properties in `GitVersion.yml` through the `{env:ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE}` syntax.

Comment: Thanks! is there a `-format` property for the NuGet variables?

Comment: No, but you can use the NuGet variables within the `-format` properties of the configuration.